# How to add apostrophe as allowed character to existing regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, apostrophe, single-quotes

I have the following regular expression for one of my name fields in C# web app:

```
^[A-Za-zÀ-ſ0-9.,#&-/'_!@;]?[a-zA-ZÀ-ſ0-9 '#&-/.,_:!@;]*[A-Za-zÀ-ſ0-9.,#-/_!@;]$
```

How can I properly modify it to add apostrophe/single quote character (') as an allowed character to it?

Comment: Doesn't it already? https://regex101.com/r/mJ0lX9/1

Comment: with slash, like this \'

Comment: or put an `@` before the string to make it [raw string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: It doesn't for some reason.

public const string REGEX_NAME = "^[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u017F0-9.,#&-/'_!@;]?[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F0-9 '#&-/.,_:!@;]*[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u017F0-9.,#-/_!@;]$";


(when debugging , the REGEX_NAME value displays as the string I pasted earlier)

The following returns false:
Regex.IsMatch("Peter's String", FieldRuleConstants.REGEX_NAME)

Comment: it might be something wrong with the existing RegEx but making it raw string has not helped in my case :(

Answer (score 1):

`'` is used for declaring a char, so put a backslash in front of the `'` to escape it, like this `\'`.

Comment: Can you please advise where should it be put in my RegEx? Again, this is how my RegEx string is definded: "^[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u017F0-9.,#&-/'_!@;]?[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F0-9 '#&-/.,_:!@;]*[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u017F0-9.,#-/_!@;]$"

Comment: Your code should be `public const string REGEX_NAME = "^[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u017F0-9.,#&-/'!@;]?[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F0-9 '#&-/.,:!@;]*[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u017F0-9.,#-/_!@;]$";`

Comment: Tried it but it still fails. Backslashed in front of the apostrophes do not seem to be visible when debugging. I also used '\u005C' instead of '\' but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the RegEx has been fine, and it was the way the data has been input into database that caused the problem. Insert statements should have the apostrophes escaped. Even though the apostrophes were getting displayed correctly, they had been failing the RegEx check due to lack of escaping  apostrophes. Thanks for your advice and sorry in case of any disapointment!